# Tooltip doesn't work on datatables child rows

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

[Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) doesn't work on child rows with jQuery DataTables.

With `fnDrawCallback` it works on usual rows, but it has no effect on child rows, and I have no idea how to make it works.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
   $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();        
}
```

See [Child rows](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) and [fnDrawCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) for reference.

**HTML Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">

    <title>DataTables example - Child rows (show extra / detailed information)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/syntax/shCore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/demo.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">

td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}

    </style>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/syntax/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">


/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Tooltip:</td>'+
            '<td><span rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="display the tooltip" class="souligne">text with a tooltip</span></td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
           $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();         
        },      
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );


    </script>
</head>

<body class="dt-example">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <h1>DataTables example <span>Child rows (show extra / detailed information)</span></h1>


            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </section>

        <h1>Tooltip works outside:</h1>
        <span rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="display the tooltip" class="souligne">text with a tooltip</span>       
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**AJAX source:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "<span rel=\"tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"\" data-original-title=\"this is a tooltip\" class=\"souligne\">Tiger Nixon<\/span>",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "<span rel=\"tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"\" data-original-title=\"this is a tooltip\" class=\"souligne\">Test tooltip<\/span>",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$327,900",
      "start_date": "2010/10/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "6200"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael Bruce",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2011/06/27",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also see that if you remove:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
   $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();         
},
```

usual rows containing a tooltip won't work.

**Sources:**

- http://datatables.net/download/packages
- http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

Just change the file `row_details.html` with my html code to see the test case (and add the file `objects.txt` to the same folder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try providing `tooltip` as below and not in `fnDrawCallBak` but on `$(document).ready`

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
});
```

Comment: So I removed fnDrawCallBak and I did: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();     
});` but it's still the same problem and usual rows doesn't display the tooltip

Comment: You haven't replaced `fnCallDrawBack` with `$(document).ready` right? This should be outside from dataTables!

Comment: Yes I did it outside datatables, without fnDrawCallBak (only $(document).ready) and with fnDrawCallBak (both in the file)

Comment: Can you show the html structure too? So that I can create a demo and cross verify?

Comment: I edited the post above you got all, just download datatables and replace the file with my code. Thanks

Comment: @Alex1 You haven't given it properly in `document.ready`. Check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0t8v30sz/3/)**. You pasted it as `$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});` whereas `data-toggle`  should have been `rel`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! But I'm wondering why it doesn't work when I do this: `$(function() { $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip(); });`

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Didn't know about the [`selector`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options) option, great answer +1!

Comment: @Alex1 since it is a dynamically added element you need kind of event delegation which is how you can do it with tooltip's `selector` option.. Your code mentioned in comments would definitely work for already placed element.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, awesome!

Answer (score 8):

Use [`createdRow`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) to initialize tooltips in regular rows.

```js
"createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', row).tooltip();
}
```

Regarding the child rows, modify your code as follows:

```js
// Open this row
row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
tr.addClass('shown');

// Initialize tooltips in the child row that follows the parent row      
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', tr.next('tr')).tooltip();
```

See the snippet below for code and demonstration.

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Tooltip:</td>'+
            '<td><span rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="display the tooltip" class="souligne">text with a tooltip</span></td>'+
        '</tr>'+      
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var data = [{"name":"<span rel=\"tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"\" data-original-title=\"this is a tooltip\" class=\"souligne\">Tiger Nixon</span>","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"<span rel=\"tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"\" data-original-title=\"this is a tooltip\" class=\"souligne\">Garrett Winters</span>","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"<span rel=\"tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"\" data-original-title=\"this is a tooltip\" class=\"souligne\">Ashton Cox</span>","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}];
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": data,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', row).tooltip();
        }
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
            
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', tr.next('tr')).tooltip();
        }
    } );
 
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: plus 1 for your efforts too as this also works well.. :)